# How to access Thunderbird's toolbar-button-icons?

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Where can I find Thunderbird's default toolbar-button-icons - I've looked around here http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/themes/winstripe/global/ without success.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird source code lives in the `comm-central` repository, not `mozilla-central`. The default Windows theme is Qute. Which makes it much easier to find the icons:

- [Windows Aero icons for the main window](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/themes/qute/mail/icons/mail-toolbar-aero.png)
- [Windows Aero icons for the Compose window](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/themes/qute/mail/compose/compose-toolbar-aero.png)